# Rolling count of boolean values in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the number of True on a 4-day rolling basis in a python dataframe like the `CountTrue` column below. What is the most efficient way to do so?

```
        Boolean:     CountTrue:     
2/01/19 True         3        
1/31/19 True         2        
1/30/19 False        1        
1/29/19 True         1        
1/28/19 False        1        
1/27/19 False        2        
1/26/19 False        2        
1/25/19 True         2        
1/24/19 True         NaN        
1/23/19 False        NaN        
1/22/29 False        NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `rolling` sum and `shift`

```
df['CountTrue'] = df.rolling(4)['Boolean'].sum().shift(-3)

Out[1302]:
         Boolean  CountTrue
2/01/19     True        3.0
1/31/19     True        2.0
1/30/19    False        1.0
1/29/19     True        1.0
1/28/19    False        1.0
1/27/19    False        2.0
1/26/19    False        2.0
1/25/19     True        2.0
1/24/19     True        NaN
1/23/19    False        NaN
1/22/29    False        NaN
```